# Run a parallel process saving results from a main process in Python

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, subprocess, python-asyncio

I have a function that creates some results for a list of tasks. I would like to save the results on the fly to 1) release memory compared to saving to appending to a results_list and 2) have the results of the first part in case of errors.

Here is a very short sample code:

```
for task in task_list:
    result = do_awesome_stuff_to_task(task)
    save_nice_results_to_db(result)  # Send this job to another process and let the main process continue
```

Is there a way for the main process to create results for each task in task_list and each time a result is create send this to another processor/thread to save it, so the main loop can continue without waiting for the slow saving process?

I have looked at multiprocessing, but that seems mostly to speed up the loop over task_list rather than allow a secondary sub process to do other parts of the work. I have also looked into asyncio, but that seems mostly used for I/O.

All in all, I am looking for a way to have a main process looping over the task_list. For each task finished I would like to send the results to another subprocess to save the results. Notice, the do_awesome_stuff_to_task is much faster than savings process, hence, the main loop will have reached through multiple task before the first task is saved. I have thought of two ways of tackling this:

1. Use multiple sub process to save
2. Save every xx iteration - the save_results scale okay, so perhaps the save process can save xx iteration at a time while the main loop continuous?

Is this possible to do with Python? Where to look and what key considerations to take?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: if `save_results` is slow because of disk speed, multiprocessing will probably make it worse

Comment: I may be slow for multiple reasons. No matter the case, I would like to know, if something like the requested is possible with Python

Comment: in general passing data between processes is not very fast or efficient. you may be able to reduce the overhead by using something like `multiprocessing.shared_memory` to transfer information a bit faster, but it is not straightforward. if it's possible to make `save_results` release the GIL, threading is your best bet. Again though if you rely on spinning rust, making more concurrent calls will result in slower throughput overall

Comment: perhaps I should clarify; I suggest threading over multiprocessing any time significant amounts of data need to be transferred between things happening concurrently because threads share memory space and there is no "transfer" as such. You need to protect objects from concurrent access so you don't corrupt data, but there is no transfer overhead. The GIL however limits the additional CPU benefit you can get from threads, but if you use things that release the GIL, you can get around this (including many IO operations, numpy, etc...)

Comment: @Aaron If you write your comment as an answer I'll mark it as answer  - perhaps you will give a simple example of using threads and how to release the GIL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know what will be faster in your case without testing, but here's some thoughts on how to choose what to do.

If `save_nice_results_to_db` is slow because it's writing data to disk or network, make sure you aren't already at the maximum write speed of your hardware. Depending on the server at the other end, network traffic can sometimes benefit greatly from opening multiple ports at once to read/write so long as you stay within your total network transfer speed (of the mac interface as well as your ISP). SSD's can see some limited benefit from initiating multiple reads/writes at once, but too many will hurt performance. HDD's are almost universally slower when trying to do more than one thing at once. Everything is more efficient reading/writing larger chunks at a time.

`multiprocessing` must typically transfer data between the parent and child processes using `pickle` because they don't share memory. This has a high overhead, so if `result` is a large object, you may waste more time with the added overhead of sending the data to a child process than you could save by any sort of concurrency. (emphasis on the **may**. always test for yourself). As of 3.8 the `shared_memory` module was added which may be somewhat more efficient, but is much less flexible and easy to use.

`threading` benefits from all threads sharing memory so there is zero transfer overhead to "send" data between threads. Python threads however cannot execute bytecode concurrently due to the GIL (global interpreter lock), so multiple CPU cores cannot be leveraged to increase computation speed. This is due to python itself having many parts which are not thread-safe. Specific functions written in c may release this lock to get around this issue and leverage multiple cpu cores using threads, but once execution returns to the python interpreter, that lock is held again. Typically functions involving network access or file IO can release the GIL, as the interpreter is waiting on an operating system call which is usually thread safe. Other popular libraries like Numpy also make an effort to release the GIL while doing complex math operations on large arrays. You can only release the GIL from c/c++ code however, and not from python itself.

`asyncio` should get a special mention here, as it's designed specifically with concurrent network/file operations in mind. It uses coroutines instead of threads (even lower overhead than threads, which themselves are much lower overhead than processes) to queue up a bunch of operations, then uses an operating system call to wait on any of them to finish (event loop). Using this would also require your `do_awesome_stuff_to_task` to happen in a coroutine for it to happen at the same time as `save_nice_results_to_db`.

A trivial example of firing each `result` off to a thread to be processed:

```
for task in task_list:
    result = do_awesome_stuff_to_task(task)
    threading.Thread(target=save_nice_results_to_db, args=(result,)).start()  # Send this job to another process and let the main process continue
```